# how to get wordpress data in fishpig magento integration

Tags: php, database, wordpress, integrate, dynamic

I need to crease a author block for the wordpress posts in fishpig integration furthermore I need to create an author profile page and recommended posts etc.
However inorder to do this I need to access wordpress database values ...Does this extension already reference this data eg:display name post date etc ...are there any other lines of code that reference wordpress data?... like in these lines of code

```
$post->getPostDate(), $post->getAuthor()->getDisplayName()
```

or would I have to make a custom query to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under /app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/Model, you should find some files including these fields.

- **Post.php** accesses post data
- **User.php** accesses author data
- **Term.php** accesses category data

From your description, most of the information you're looking for will be in Post.php and User.php

---

**Examples:**

From the post view and any other pages with access to the post class, you can use these:

```
$post->getPostTitle()  // Post's display name
$post->getPostDate()   // Post's date
$post->getAuthor()     // Post's author, allows access to methods in the User.php file
$post->getAuthor()->getFirstName()  // Author's first name from Wordpress
$post->getAuthor()->getGravatarUrl()  // The url to the author's Gravatar image
$post->getParentTerm('category')  // Post's category, allows access to methods in the Term.php file
$post->getParentTerm('category')->getUrl()  // Category's url
$post->getParentTerm('category')->getPostCount()  // Total number of posts in the category
```

From the user view and any other pages with access to the user class directly, you can use these:

```
$author->getFirstName()
$author->getGravatarUrl()
```

From the term / category views and any other pages with access to the term class directly:

```
$term->getUrl()
$term->getPostCount()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..could you please provide me with an example of how you would use functions in these files, please it would be a massive help. Thanks

Comment: Hi Brad,  I updated the post to include a few examples.

Comment: @BenLeBlanc hi have you know how fishpig is working in magento2?